# Use Both Active Directory and OpenID Authentication

Tags: asp.net, authentication, ldap, openid

How can I use both Active directory authentication and OpenID authentication in my ASP.NET/C# application? I found many articles which show separate methods for both LDAP and OpenID authentication. I want to use them in single authentication mechanism.

Comment: This is an interesting use case. Do the requirements specify a multi-factor authentication where authentication against Active Directory and OpenID must both succeed, or does the requirement specify that either must succeed? Which of the authentication methods are to be considered authoritative?